# Sherlock tabs not working on orientation change

Tags: android, tabs, android-actionbar, orientation, fragment

I managet to set up three tabs using Sherlock ActionBar. The only problem is that when orientation is changed, tabs can not be tapped any more. It seem like the onTabSelected() is not called. Example: I am in portrait and the tab2 is selected. I change into lanscape. Tab2 is still selected, I tap tab3 but nothing happens. Then when I go back to portrait again, tab3 is shown. I am testing in Android 2.3.6.

This is the main activity:

```
public class Activity_Main extends SherlockFragmentActivity {
    ActionBar.Tab tab1, tab2, tab3;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setTabs();
    }
    void setTabs(){
        ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();

        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

        tab1 = actionBar.newTab();
        tab2 = actionBar.newTab();
        tab3 = actionBar.newTab();
        tab1.setText("Week");
        tab2.setText("Today");
        tab3.setText("ToDo");

        tab1.setTabListener(new TabListener<Fragment_Start_Week>(this, "week", Fragment_Start_Week.class));
        tab2.setTabListener(new TabListener<Fragment_Start_Today>(this, "today", Fragment_Start_Today.class));
        tab3.setTabListener(new TabListener<Fragment_Start_Todo>(this, "todo", Fragment_Start_Todo.class));
    }
    private class TabListener<T extends SherlockFragment> implements com.actionbarsherlock.app.ActionBar.TabListener{

        private SherlockFragment mFragment;
        private final Activity mActivity;
        private final String mTag;
        private final Class<T> mClass;
        /**
         * Constructor used each time a new tab is created.
         * 
         * @param activity
         *            The host Activity, used to instantiate the fragment
         * @param tag
         *            The identifier tag for the fragment
         * @param clz
         *            The fragment's Class, used to instantiate the fragment
         */
        public TabListener(Activity activity, String tag, Class<T> clz) {
            mActivity = activity;
            mTag = tag;
            mClass = clz;
        }

        /* The following are each of the ActionBar.TabListener callbacks */

        public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        SherlockFragment preInitializedFragment = (SherlockFragment) ((FragmentActivity) mActivity).getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(mTag);

        // Check if the fragment is already initialized
        if (mFragment == null && preInitializedFragment == null) {
            // If not, instantiate and add it to the activity
            mFragment = (SherlockFragment) SherlockFragment.instantiate(mActivity, mClass.getName());
            ft.add(android.R.id.content, mFragment, mTag);
        } else if (mFragment != null) {
            // If it exists, simply attach it in order to show it
            ft.attach(mFragment);
        } else if (preInitializedFragment != null) {
            ft.attach(preInitializedFragment);
            mFragment = preInitializedFragment;
        }
    }

        public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
            if (mFragment != null) {
                // Detach the fragment, because another one is being attached
                ft.detach(mFragment);
            }
        }
        @Override
        public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }
}
```

This is a fragment:

```
public class Fragment_Start_Week extends SherlockFragment implements OnClickListener{

    void create_table() { 
                ...
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup group, Bundle saved)
    {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_start_week, group, false);
    }
    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        create_table();
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        ...

    }

}
```

TIA

Comment: Did u resolve this problem? I am curious because even I am experiencing the same.

Comment: Not yet:( I couldn't find any help for this problem. Please if you find any solution, write it here as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a lot of trial and errors I've found the following solution for this bug:

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_LIST);
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
}
```

The trick is to change the navigation mode to list then change back to tabs.